Exporting a const from an external file to use in ReactSearchAutocomplete doesn't work
I'm building a Pokémon team generator and the user should be able to use ReactSearchAutocomplete before I fetch data from an external API. I wrote an external file including information like pokemon name and id, it looks like this:
const pokemonlist = [
  {
    name: "bulbasaur",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "ivysaur",
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    name: "venusaur",
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    name: "terapagos",
    id: 1024,
  },
  {
    name: "pecharunt",
    id: 1025,
  },
];

export default pokemonlist;

Since the file is more than 4100 lines long I shortened it here so that it's easier to read for you.
In my second file for the actual Searchbar Component I wrote this:
import pokemonlist from "./pokemon/pokemonlist";
import { ReactSearchAutocomplete } from "react-search-autocomplete";

export default function SearchbarAutocomplete() {
  
  const handleOnSearch = (string, results) => {
    // console.log(string, results);
  };

  const handleOnHover = (result) => {
    console.log(result);
  };

  const handleOnSelect = (item) => {
    console.log(item);
  };

  const handleOnFocus = () => {
    // console.log("Focused");
  };

  const formatResult = (item) => {
    return (
      <>
        <span style={{ display: "block", textAlign: "left" }}>
          #{item.id} {item.name}
        </span>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <ReactSearchAutocomplete
      items={pokemonlist}
      onSearch={handleOnSearch}
      onHover={handleOnHover}
      onSelect={handleOnSelect}
      onFocus={handleOnFocus}
      autoFocus
      formatResult={formatResult}
      placeholder="Search Pokemon"
    />
  );
}

Doing it like this the pokemonlist is not found. There's no error in my console but I get the fallback "No results". I also tried using a named export, same thing happens.
If I place the const inside the SearchbarAutocomplete function, everything works as expected, it looks like this:
import pokemonlist from "./pokemon/pokemonlist";
import { ReactSearchAutocomplete } from "react-search-autocomplete";

export default function SearchbarAutocomplete() {

const pokemonlist = [
  {
    name: "bulbasaur",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "ivysaur",
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    name: "venusaur",
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    name: "terapagos",
    id: 1024,
  },
  {
    name: "pecharunt",
    id: 1025,
  },
];
  
  const handleOnSearch = (string, results) => {
    // console.log(string, results);
  };

  const handleOnHover = (result) => {
    console.log(result);
  };

  const handleOnSelect = (item) => {
    console.log(item);
  };

  const handleOnFocus = () => {
    // console.log("Focused");
  };

  const formatResult = (item) => {
    return (
      <>
        <span style={{ display: "block", textAlign: "left" }}>
          #{item.id} {item.name}
        </span>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <ReactSearchAutocomplete
      items={pokemonlist}
      onSearch={handleOnSearch}
      onHover={handleOnHover}
      onSelect={handleOnSelect}
      onFocus={handleOnFocus}
      autoFocus
      formatResult={formatResult}
      placeholder="Search Pokemon"
    />
  );
}

But >4000 lines of text... I'd really like to separate these information from my actual code. Can you help me here please? What do I miss?

Some suggestions: Try to reduce the pokemonlist  file size to 2k entries, then 1k entries, etc. to verify that the size is actually the issue and not something else. I'd keep data like that in a .json file btw, most bundlers should be able to import it and it makes the intention a bit clearer (that it contains static data not code).

Moving the file into another folder solved it. It's quite slow all in all so if the application is too slow in the end I might switch to using a .json file instead of what I did. Thank you!

Great that you managed to solve it. Though I doubt that using .json means performance improvements, it all gets parsed into a JS object that's used at runtime.
